# GCM 8.4.0 Connetion Failed due to Permission on Android 6

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging, android-6.0-marshmallow

I want to add GCM to my application and register user device but I have weird problem:

```
W/GMPM: Service connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_MISSING_PERMISSION, resolution=PendingIntent{c28038b: android.os.BinderProxy@6a00c68}, message=null}
```

The device can't register and I can't get the register token. How can I fix this?

My manifest file permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:name="ir.makbn.mashfood.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="ir.makbn.mashfood.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
```

and my receiver class definition:

```
 <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="ir.makbn.mashfood.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service
        android:name=".service.MyGcmListener"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".service.MyInstanceIDListener"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

All my receivers classes are same as in the Google GCM example and I use GCM 8.4.0.

In my shared preferences I found `com.google.android.gcm.measurement.prefs` that contains:

```
...name="health_monitor_value">1wc8487:service connection faild: _ ...
```

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe it's using a dangerous permission that needs to be granted at run time check out dangerous permissions here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#perm-groups also requesting permissions at run time http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @SaNtoRiaN no its not caused by dangerous permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the  [Official Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult) the error code used by GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener. 
Google Play Service doesn't have one or more required permissions. The client may call  ['startResolutionForResult(Activity, int)'](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult#public-methods) to prompt the user to fix the issue. After activity returns with ['RESULT_OK'](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_OK) further attempts to connect should succeed.

A Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) Android client is a client app that runs on an Android device. We recommend that you use the GoogleCloudMessaging API and Android Studio with Gradle.

There are requirements for running a GCM Android client, GCM implementation requires both client implementation and server implementation. For more details about GCM android client, check this: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start

Comment: can you post example for startResolutionForResult(Activity, int)  to fix issue when google play service doesn't have permission? your answer is correct thank you